# phpMyAdmin displays error when importing database

Tags: php, database, sql, import, phpmyadmin

I'm migrating a WordPress for a friend to a different server. I have already backed up all files and was given a copy of the database by the old server admin. The problem is that when I try and import the database using phpMyAdmin, I get this error message:

``` SQL query:  -- -- Database: ``wordpress_6`` -- CREATE DATABASE  ``wordpress_6`` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;   MySQL said: Documentation  #1044 - Access denied for user 'prvtres9'@'localhost' to database 'wordpress_6 ```

I'm not sure what would initiate this error message, but the tiny amount of information I found out in several hours of frustration eludes that it could be in the way the database was copied, therefore putting me in a helpless position, but I don't want to approach the old server admin just to be wrong about this

Comment: Try creating a database first and then importing, it's a permissions issue.

Comment: What do you mean? The database was created first, I don't understand how I could import it if it wasn't created first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have already created the database that you wish to import into and you have selected that database in PHPMyAdmin, but the import file is trying to create a new database, then you will see this error message.

All you need to do is open up the SQL file in a text editor and delete the line that begins with `CREATE DATABASE` (it will be very near the top of the file).

Now try the import again and it should import that data into your selected database rather than trying to create a new one.